# GDScript Animation issues

Tags: game-engine, godot, gdscript

I am trying to insert animations in all directions, but entering the String **"update_animation_parameters(input_direction)"** I find this Error **"built-in:23 - Parse Error: Unexpected token: Identifier:update_animation_parameters"**

`

```
extends KinematicBody2D

export (int) var speed = 150
export var starting_direction : Vector2 = Vector2(0, 1)

var velocity = Vector2()

onready var animation_tree = $AnimationTree

func _ready():
    animation_tree.set("parameters/Idle/blend_position", starting_direction)
func get_input():
    velocity = Vector2()
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        velocity.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        velocity.y -= 1
    update_animation_parameters(input_direction)
    
    velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed

func _physics_process(_delta):
    get_input()
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
    
func update_animation_parameters(move_input : Vector2):
    if(move_input != Vector2.ZERO):
        animation_tree.set("parameters/Walk/blend_position", move_input)
        animation_tree.set("parameters/Idle/blend_position", move_input)
```

```
`

**I don’t know how to fix it**
```

Comment: While I can't reproduce that *specific* error message, you don't seem to have declared the variable `input_direction` anywhere. Are you sure that's the error you're getting?

Comment: Whenever you get an error saying that something was "Unexpected" think it means that the system was expecting something else. Figure out what. You usually have to look just before where it shows the error. It might be that you missed some keyword, or had some strange character, or wrong indentation, stuff like that. The code seems fine on a first inspection, however, I believe you are excluding some parts in the interest of making the question short… Yet the problem is likely in those parts.

Comment: Yea, quite sure

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't declared an `input_direction` variable, you're not passing in a value to `update_animation_parameters` - you're passing an argument that doesn't exist.  Try modifying your `get_input` method as follows:

```
func get_input():
    velocity = Vector2()
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        velocity.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        velocity.y -= 1

    update_animation_parameters(velocity)
    velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed
```